# can you recommend a really super native delphi graphing engine?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, charts, graphing

we've been using Pro Essentials graph (gigasoft.com) but it doesn't play nicely with delphi so it's been causing problems.

we need to display waveforms and bar graphs (not at the same time).  the waveforms could have thousands of points.  we need something pretty full-featured that's a "living" product.

our app is a native win32 delphi 2009 app.

thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try TeeChart

http://www.steema.com/

Comment: We have used TeeChart in our application and it works like a charm.

Comment: +1 I've been using TeeChart for 10 years, and they keep improving it!

Comment: Excellent tool and wonderful support - which is hardly ever needed. Been using it also for around 10 years.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion--we'll look into it!

Answer (score 3):

how about [aggpas](http://aggpas.org) ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try out the [LMD ChartPack](http://www.lmd.de/products/vcl/lmdchartpack/).  LMD has been making native Delphi products for years - if they handle your scenario, they will probably work quite well.

Some wave forms and bar graphics should both be able to be done with that.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion--we'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

[Try this link](http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatpmapchart.htm). It has many components listed just for Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

Try our **RMChart**.

Not native Delphi component but a freeware one and I have been using it in many of my apps.

Comment: Do you have some Delphi specific examples showing how to use these?

Comment: Sorry none as still VB.net & C# are our mail development tool at the place where I work.

I have experimented with it in Delphi but have used the ActiveX version instead of dirtying my hands with writing declarations for using the DLL version.